# toggle a program using bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, background-process, redshift

I am trying to make a script that will toggle `redshift` (a night mode application). So, I've done this,

```
#!/bin/bash

pgrep redshift > /dev/null && \ 
         killall redshift || \
         setsid redshift [options] &> /dev/null
```

This looks up for the program and if that program is running in the background then it is killed otherwise it is started and is `setsid`. 
Now, this script works if I am to kill the process, but this script hangs when I  run it back.

- What am I doing wrong?
- Is there other ways to put the process background so that killing the
  terminal won't stop the program?

Comment: I think you could simplify slightly by using just `pgrep redshift > /dev/null && ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you invoke the program with bash, bash interprets `&>` as a special redirection operator (redirect both stdout and stderr), and not as you may have intended: a background operator `&` and a stdout redirection `>`. Separate the two tokens and you'll get the background behavior you're expecting:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

pgrep redshift > /dev/null && 
  killall redshift || 
    setsid redshift [options] & > /dev/null
```

Consider being kinder to your future self and expand the logic slightly; you want to kill `redshift` if it's there, then start it with some options:

```
if pgrep redshift > /dev/null
then
  pkill redshift
fi
setsid redshift options & > /dev/null
```

Answer (score 3):

### redshift has a toggle feature

Send signal SIGUSR1 to the redshift process to toggle:

```
pkill -USR1 redshift
```

It is documented [on their website](http://jonls.dk/redshift/), but not in the [software’s documentation](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/redshift/redshift.1.en.html). I had opened a [pull request](https://github.com/jonls/redshift/pull/697) to document this feature in its man page.

Answer (score 0):

I use this to toggle my desktop icons in Gnome.

```
pkill nemo-desktop || nemo-desktop
```

Of course this works for redshift too.

```
pkill redshift || redshift
```